# ManyToMany on same Entity with field from MappedSuperclass

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I would like to create `ManyToMany` relationship with same table on both side. It should represent friendship between two users. I have now User class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
public class User extends BaseObject implements UserDetails {

    //example of others relationship
    private Set<Post> posts;

     @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true
        , mappedBy = "author")
    @OrderBy("dateOfCreation DESC")
    public Set<Post> getPosts() {
        return posts;
    }

    public void setPosts(Set<Post> posts) {
        this.posts = posts;
    }
}
```

and the `@MappedSuperclass`

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseObject {

    /** Object id */
    private Long id;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Because I want to add some new columns to this relationship I have to create new Entity which will be used as joining table. So I have know `UserFriend`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "UserFriends")
public class UserFriend {

    /** User */
    private User user;
    /** User's friend */
    private User friend;
    /** Pending friendship*/
    private boolean accepted;

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public User getFriend() {
        return friend;
    }

    public void setFriend(User friend) {
        this.friend = friend;
    }

    //other getter setter
}
```

Now I need  to connect these tables. I would like to use `user_id` and `friend_id` pointing to `id` field of `User` entity. But I'm not sure how to achieve this. Can you please give me hint how to user right annotations? Or give me better approach (using new fields user for example).

Answer (score 0):

You can use unidirectional `ManyToOne` mapping.

```
/** User */
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User user;

/** User's friend */
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "friend_id")
private User friend;
```

Hibernate generates the Table `UserFriends` with the columns `user_id` and `friend_id`. The columns contain the connected Users referenced by the `Id` of the mapped superclass.

A quick verification of the DDL-Statements generated by Hibernate confirms the functionality.

```
create table UserFriends (id bigint not null, accepted boolean not null, friend_id bigint, user_id bigint, primary key (id))


create table Users (id bigint not null, primary key (id))
```